# swf file is not uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, flash

Other file listed is uploading fine, but swf file is not uploading and giving a error of file type is not supported.

Here is my controller

```
function do_upload(){
    $pid=$this->input->post('Page_id');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'swf|png|gif|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '1048';
    $config['file_name'] =$pid;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('admin/upload', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->upload_success();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are creating the right form - **multipart** `<?php echo form_open_multipart();?>`

Answer (score 0):

might be a bug with the File Upload Class in the _file_mime_type function
`look for more` [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/204725/)

Comment: i checked it on my 1058 line number is similar to the correct format

Comment: @RahatIslamKhan look at the function reference here Function Referenceellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
you should provide the field name.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pass the the field name in the `do_upload` call  like

```
  $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|swf|png', // pipe seperated file types
        'upload_path' => './uploads/',// should be the root path
        'max_size' => '1048',
        'file_name' =>$pid
        );
$this->load->library('upload', $config );

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('your_field_name')){  
// like  $this->upload->do_upload($pid)
 $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

 }else{
 $swf_data = $this->upload->data(); 
  }
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: _sidenote_: `do_upload()` does take parameter but it is mandatory. Default value is **userfile**.

Comment: i tried but again it shows me an error The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: are you sure your file type is `.swf` without spaces in it i have edited my answer there was a space